# How to make the worker continuously run in PHP - Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, web-worker

I am creating a php application which inserts the record in the DB for every 10 - 20 automatically in heroku to achieve that i had created a proc file and i'm using worker inside that . While deploying the application in the heroku there is found out while running the worker [image] I am new to this heroku and PHP. Can any one help me on what this mean and how can i resolve it and make the worker run continuously to insert the record in the Database.

This is line in my proc file contains which is under root of the project

```
worker: php /app/worker/db_worker.php
```

My db_worker.php:

```
<?php
    include_once "./db_config.php";
        $conn = $connection;
        $number_1 = rand(1,50);
        $number_2 = rand(60,500);
        
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO random_numbers (num_1, num_2) VALUES ('".$number_1."', '".$number_2."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $insertQuery);
        if($result) {
            echo 'Details saved';
            
        } else {
            echo 'Failed to save details';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to run your operations in a loop. For example,

```php
<?php
while (true) {
        // assume this can be included repeatedly
        include_once "./db_config.php";

        $conn = $connection;
        $number_1 = rand(1,50);
        $number_2 = rand(60,500);
        
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO random_numbers (num_1, num_2) VALUES ('".$number_1."', '".$number_2."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $insertQuery);
        if($result) {
            echo 'Details saved';
            
        } else {
            echo 'Failed to save details';
        }


        // recommend to do some memory clean up
        // ...
        
        // wait for 5 seconds
        sleep(5);
}
```

But there's a problem. PHP is not considered memory safe. There can be memory leak issue(s) running it for really long time. If this didn't work well, you might simply do this as a static script with the help of scheduler services like [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution it's working well